# How to serialize an object that implements Serializable but contains fields that do not?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-commons

The specific library I'm using is the Apache Commons CSV library v1.8 (latest). I'm trying to serialize an object that contains a CSVRecord but lets look at its code:

```
public final class CSVRecord implements Serializable, Iterable<String> {
    private static final String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[0];
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final long characterPosition;
    private final String comment;
    private final long recordNumber;
    private final String[] values;
    private final CSVParser parser;
```

It implements `Serializable`, however it contains a CSVParser which is NOT serializable:

```
public final class CSVParser implements Iterable<CSVRecord>, Closeable {
    private final CSVFormat format;
    private final Map<String, Integer> headerMap;
    private final List<String> headerNames;
    private final Lexer lexer;
    private final CSVParser.CSVRecordIterator csvRecordIterator;
    private final List<String> recordList;
    private long recordNumber;
    private final long characterOffset;
    private final Token reusableToken;
```

Is there some way to get around this without altering the library to make this a transient field? Is this just an oversight by the authors, or is there some way to serialize the CSVRecord that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Nice catch! :) I went through the code too and found no way to work around the problem without touching the library code. But even this has issues as I see.

I think the reason why `CSVParser` is not `Serializable` is because it keeps the file open till the reading is complete. If it is allowed to be serialized, then it means that during deserialization (possibly on another system or at a time when the file no longer exists) the object still refers to file!

So, even if you change the library code to, say, remove `final` from `CSVParser` and write a serializable subclass or make `parser` field `transient` in `CSVRecord`, it will still not help because the deserialized class will not work, as explained above.

Hence, I see only non-class-serialization way feasible (ie, to JSON or `Map`, etc.).

Comment: Ah I see. I spent a ton of time getting my class ready to be serializable but I should have looked closer at that class. I might try reporting this as a bug and see what they say!

Comment: From a class design point-of-view, yes, there is a contradiction here that though ```CSVRecord``` is designed to be serialized, it cannot be. So, I think you have a case here to raise a defect. You will, in the least, get a better explanation!

Comment: I posted a bug on the apache commons Jira thing and this was indeed an oversight. They said it should be set as transient. woo!

Comment: Super! Now there is a contribution from your side in Apache Commons! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `transient` keyword of java.

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part
>   of the persistent state of an object.

So the above serializable class become

```
public final class CSVRecord implements Serializable, Iterable<String> {
    private static final String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[0];
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final long characterPosition;
    private final String comment;
    private final long recordNumber;
    private final String[] values;
    private final transient CSVParser parser;
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```